# Elements with norm $1$ in a quadratic field

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Consider the number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and the norm map $N:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \to \mathbb{Q}^*$ given by $N(a+b \sqrt{5})=a^2-5b^2$.

Is there an explicit description of the kernel of this map, i.e of the elements having norm  $=1$?

Comment: Do you know Hilbert 90?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Pell’s equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Pell gives only the integer solutions, not the rational ones. Hilbert's 90 is the correct tool here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilbert's Theorem 90 implies that any such element may be written in the form $\frac{a-b\sqrt{5}}{a+b\sqrt{5}}$ for $a,b \in \Bbb Q$. You can achieve $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ by multiplying with a common denominator.

Answer (score 1):

in lowest terms, the ones with even denominator are
$$   a = \frac{2u^2 + 2uv + 3 v^2}{2 u^2 + 2uv - 2 v^2} \; , \; \; b =  \frac{ 2uv + v^2 }{2 u^2 + 2uv - 2 v^2}  $$

Odd
$$   a = \frac{u^2  + 5 v^2}{ u^2 - 5 v^2} \; , \; \; b =  \frac{ 2uv  }{ u^2  - 5 v^2}  $$

there should be conditions mod 2,5 to enforce no common factors

If you just want integers
$a_n^2 - 5 b_n^2 = 1$  in sequence $a_{n+2} = 18 a_{n+1} - a_n$  and $b_{n+2} = 18 b_{n+1} - b_n$
beginning with pairs $(1,0)$   and $(9,4)$ and $(161,72)$